# How to check the children of div container had been fulfill or not in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I not sure how to describe in the title.So,just give more information here.

I have a **container div class=container** with **random children link a tag inside**.E.g:

```
<div class='container' style='width:200px; height:25px;overflow:hidden;'>
  <a href='' style='display:block;float:left;padding:1px 3px'>people name here[long or short]</a>
  ..... <!--random total of name's link-->
</div>
```

So, in some cases there was **only one** name and didn't go outside of the container but in another case, **the count of name were outside of the container** and I want to put a tip or something beside to note that there were more name here didn't display.

Thank you very much!!

**[update]**

for example:

if link inside of container is:

```
<a href='' style='display:block;float:left;padding:1px 3px'>join keviin</a>
<a href='' style='display:block;float:left;padding:1px 3px'>my second name</a>
<a href='' style='display:block;float:left;padding:1px 3px'>I am not seem</a>
```

with the **style** applied. the **first one link's width**  maybe **80px** , and **second link's width maybe 100px** and so on, so , with the **container** only **200px width** and **doesn't have enough space for the third link**, and the third link world be moved to the next line , because the **container's overflow is set to hidden**, so the third link will not be seem, and in this case , I have to make a tip or flag beside to note users that there are more link here ....and let user to click to see the third link....

Comment: So, you have N number of child elements, and you want to do what? If I understand you, you'd like to check for each child element if its content is too long, or limit the number of child elements and display tip if neccessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the links in another child div, and then compare the width and height of that with the parent. The child div will have the full width/height of its contents (but hidden because of the overflow).

```
<div class='container' style='width:200px; height:25px;overflow:hidden;'>
  <div class="link_container">
  <a href=''>people name here[long or short]</a>
  ..... <!--random total of name's link-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".container").each(function() 
{
   var container = $(this);
   var links = container.find(".link_container");

   if(links.width() > container.width() || links.height() > container.height())
   {
        // show tip
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a title on your a-elements:

```
<a href="#" title="Long name string">Long na...</a>
```

When you mouse-over on the link, you will see a tip-text pop up with whatever text defined in the title-attribute.